# Time course stackbar chart with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I want to create a stack bar chart with openpyxl. On my excel sheet, each col is a time point with data of different categories. From openpyxl tutorial, it seems to be straightforward to create bar charts if I have each time point per row. But I don't have the freedom to switch rows and cols. Is there a way to create stack chart with each bar for a time point and each category of that time point stacking up, please? Below are some sample data:

[image: sample data]

I want to create a chart like:

[image: chart to create:]

Comment: Do I understand this right? you want to swap titles and categories with respect to the example [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/bar.html#vertical-horizontal-and-stacked-bar-charts) without changing your actual cell data?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I find with openpyxl I almost always have to just look at the source code. In particular, I fire up [spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) so I can use its "go to definition (Ctrl-G)" feature to follow the source.

Comment: As Aaron says, this is really just a question of passing in the `from_rows=True` parameter. The docs were based on the default behaviour in GUI. Improvements are always welcome.

Answer (score 3):

I modified the example from [here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/charts/bar.html#vertical-horizontal-and-stacked-bar-charts) to use your example. The primary change is to tell the `add_data()` method of the chart that you have rows of data instead of columns using the keyword argument: `from_rows=True`. The only other changes are the row and column numbers to get the correct references.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

wb = Workbook(write_only=True)
ws = wb.create_sheet()

rows = [
    ('Mon/Cat', '2018-08', '2018-09', '2018-10', '2018-11'),
    ('Cat 101', 885, 3378, 0, 2155),
    ('Cat 102', 0, 458, 1255, 0),
    ('Cat 103', 474, 0, 1554, 1655),
    ('Cat 104', 1250, 250, 502, 845),
]


for row in rows:
    ws.append(row)


chart1 = BarChart()
chart1.type = "col"
chart1.style = 10
chart1.grouping = "stacked"
chart1.overlap = 100
chart1.title = "Chart Title"
#chart1.y_axis.title = 'y-axis'
#chart1.x_axis.title = 'x-axis'

data = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=5, max_col=5)
cats = Reference(ws, min_col=2, min_row=1, max_col=5)
chart1.add_data(data, from_rows=True, titles_from_data=True)
chart1.set_categories(cats)
chart1.shape = 4
ws.add_chart(chart1, "A10")

wb.save("bar.xlsx")
```

Comment: The default graphics settings for me are a little different from the image you posted (outlines, drop shadows, gridlines, etc.) These are all possible to be changed, but will require much digging to find the exact properties needed. I have in the past created a minimal excel file, renamed it to `.zip` and opened up the internal xml to find property names for things I was looking for. The way openpyxl works, this should let you do about anything, but it won't necessarily be easy to find out how.

Comment: I'd say don't blame the library, blame the OOXML specification! ;-) At least because openpyxl follows the specification you can normally get it to do what you want. Except where it's not explained as in combining charts.

Comment: I was surprised that chart1.overlap = 100 is not the default for a stacked column chart.